# Turn auto-sync on in Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I've found this problem a few times on the web, but no answer:
I'm running an android application (using C2DM) on an emulator using a google api avd (api 8 upwards, tried a few of them). I've managed to register a google account on the device, but it says "sync is off".
Anybody knows how to turn this on?

Answer (score 1):

Try the latest version of Google API's Add-on with an emulator and it may have solved the issue of using the account's sync on. as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/gaOiZ4RsTcw). Not guaranteed though !

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I'm currently not working on this but try out some time!

Answer (score 0):

You need [install Google Apps](http://senk9.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/how-to-install-google-apps-gapps-on-your-android-device-phone/)